# Run time error 9 after creating new tabs in a worksheet

Tags: excel, runtime

Here is what I have done so far.

1. Created a workbook from an SAP data dump
2. Renamed only tab from dump "Original"
3. Used a macro to create 2 more tabs of the exact same data and renamed them "Unused" and "InvOnHand"
4. After the tabs are created the current active tab is "Unused"

I am trying to create a macro that will filter each of the new tabs based on set criteria.  That part works.  What won't work is me "activating" the new tabs.  I keep running into the Run Time Error 9(This error is thrown on the line ws2 = worksheets("InvOnHand").  My code is below(which seems to work after rewriting my code and saving it again).

```
Sub CFGKeep()
    'Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    'Set wb = Workbooks("TTB - Inv on hand - CFG_CL")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("InvOnHand")
    'wb.Activate
    ws2.Activate

    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Left(Cells(i, "H"), 2) <> "US" And Left(Cells(i, "H"), 2) <> "PD" Or Left(Cells(i, "I"), 3) = "EFN" Then
            Cells(i, "H").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Specify the workbook whose `Worksheets` collection you want.

Comment: The workbook is currently in the code as a comment.  After I re-saved the file the macro works.  But the macro, as a part of a sequence, doesn't work if I let it run without re-saving the macro file

Comment: I mean in this line: `Set ws2 = Worksheets("InvOnHand")` You shoud be specifying the workbook there - eg if `wb2` is the right one: `Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("InvOnHand")`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!